# cycling star-field animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I made this star-field animation in javascript. I'm just not sure the best way to make it cycle the same animation from the other side. I like to get the stars to scroll across from one side of the canvas to the other.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
stars = [];
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getSpeed(depth) {
  switch (depth / 2) {
    case 0:
      return 6;
    case 1:
      return 5;
    case 2:
      return 4;
    case 3:
      return 3;
    case 4:
      return 2;
    case 5:
      return 1;
  }
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  var star = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
    v: 0
  };
  star.x = getRandomInt(0, 500);
  star.y = getRandomInt(0, 500);
  star.z = getRandomInt(0, 5) * 2;
  star.v = getSpeed(star.z);
  stars.push(star);
}

function animation() {
  //clears background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  // populates space with stars
  for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + (256 / stars[i].z) + "," + (256 / stars[i].z) + "," + (256 / stars[i].z) + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(stars[i].x, stars[i].y, 2, 2);
    stars[i].x += stars[i].v;
  }

  setTimeout(animation, 33);
}
animation();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: BTW, your `getSpeed()` function body can be replaced by `return 6 - depth / 2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset the x value when it drops below zero.

```
if (star.x < 0) star.x = canvasWidth;
```

I've made a few other changes, compare.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function StarField(ctx, numStars, width, height) {
  var stars = new Array(numStars).fill(null).map(getStar);
  
  function getStar() {
    var z = getRandomInt(0, 5),
      c = (256 / z).toString(16);
    return {
      x: getRandomInt(0, width),
      y: getRandomInt(0, height),
      z: z * 2,
      v: 6 - z,
      c: "#" + c + c + c
    };
  }
  
  this.animate = function () {
    var i, s;

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for (i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
      s = stars[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = s.c;
      ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y, 2, 2);
      s.x -= s.v;
      if (s.x < 0) s.x = width;
    }
    setTimeout(this.animate.bind(this), 32);
  };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var s = new StarField(canvas.getContext("2d"), 2000, 500, 500);
s.animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse

```
stars[i].x -= stars[i].v;
```

You could loop forever and when i==1999, multiply v with -1 and set i to 0 again

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
stars = [];
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getSpeed(depth) {
  switch (depth / 2) {
    case 0:
      return 6;
    case 1:
      return 5;
    case 2:
      return 4;
    case 3:
      return 3;
    case 4:
      return 2;
    case 5:
      return 1;
  }
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  var star = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
    v: 0
  };
  star.x = getRandomInt(0, 500);
  star.y = getRandomInt(0, 500);
  star.z = getRandomInt(0, 5) * 2;
  star.v = getSpeed(star.z);
  stars.push(star);
}

function animation() {
  //clears background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  // populates space with stars
  for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + (256 / stars[i].z) + "," + (256 / stars[i].z) + "," + (256 / stars[i].z) + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(stars[i].x, stars[i].y, 2, 2);
    stars[i].x -= stars[i].v;
  }

  setTimeout(animation, 33);
}
animation();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see that the stars go both ways by adding the new property d (direction) and the direction changes when the stars reach to the end of the screen...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
stars = [];
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getSpeed( depth)
{
     switch(depth/2)
     {
       case 0:
         return 6;
       case 1:
         return 5;
       case 2:
         return 4;
       case 3:
         return 3;
       case 4:
         return 2;
       case 5:
         return 1;
     }
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  var star= { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, v: 0 };
  star.x = getRandomInt(0, 500);
  star.y = getRandomInt(0, 500);
  star.z = getRandomInt(0, 5) * 2;
  star.v = getSpeed(star.z);
  star.d = 1;
  stars.push(star);
}

function animation () {
  //clears background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  // populates space with stars
  for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + (256 / stars[i].z) + "," + (256 / stars[i].z) + "," + (256 / stars[i].z) + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(stars[i].x, stars[i].y, 2, 2);
  if(stars[i].x>=500)stars[i].d=-1;
  if(stars[i].x<=0)stars[i].d=1;
  stars[i].x += stars[i].v * stars[i].d; 
 }

   setTimeout(animation, 33);
}
animation ();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To move and repeat use the remainder operator `%`. Because it returns negative values you have to mess about a little to make sure that the numbers are always positive. Also you want to make sure that the stars only move to the other side of the canvas when they are completely off one side so the modulo value must include the star size `500+2`.

Thus star pos x

```
x %= 502;  // get remainder could be negative
x += 502;  // ensure it is positive
x %= 502;  // do modulo again
```

How I did it in your example

```
// set up
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
const starCount = 2000;
const starSize = 2;
const widthModulo = w + starSize;
const heightModulo = h + starSize;

   // in iteration

    x = ((star.x % widthModulo) + widthModulo) % widthModulo - starSize / 2;
    y = ((star.y % heightModulo) + heightModulo) % heightModulo - starSize / 2;
    // draw the star
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, starSize, starSize);
```

I have changed your code to have the stars go in many directions to show how well this method works. Also have added a few other changes. The main one is using requestAnimationFrame to call the animation function.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const stars = [];
var dir = Math.PI;
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
const starCount = 2000;
const starSize = 2;
const widthModulo = w + starSize;
const heightModulo = h + starSize;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {

  // following 4 randoms give a semi bell curve to the random value
  // this is to make more star at lower z values
  var z = (Math.random() + Math.random() +Math.random() +Math.random());
  z = Math.abs(z-2) * 8;
  var col = Math.floor(16 * z);
  stars.push({
    x: getRandomInt(0, w),
    y: getRandomInt(0, h),
    v: z / 6,
    col : "rgb("+col+","+col+","+col+")",
  });
}
stars.sort((a,b)=>a.v - b.v);  // sort from back to front

function animation (timer) {
  var star, dx, dy, x, y, i;

  // set the direction to make stars move in long circles
  dir = (Math.sin(timer / 13289) + 1) * Math.PI ; 

  //clears background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // get direction vector
  dx = Math.cos(dir);
  dy = Math.sin(dir);
  for (i = 0; i < starCount; i += 1) {
    star = stars[i];
    ctx.fillStyle = star.col;

    // move the star
    star.x += star.v * dx;
    star.y += star.v * dy;

    // make sure that stars are rendered on the current viewport
    x = ((star.x % widthModulo) + widthModulo) % widthModulo - starSize / 2;
    y = ((star.y % heightModulo) + heightModulo) % heightModulo - starSize / 2;
    // draw the star
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, starSize, starSize);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animation);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width = 500 height = 500></canvas>
```